# What is the difference between lj and ljf?

Tags: kdb

What is the difference between `lj` and `ljf`?

Looking at https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lj/ I don't `ljf` getting mentioned.

Comment: `ljf` is mentioned on that page, in the "changes in v3.0" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lj` behaviour was changed in kdb 3.0 version. Old behaviour is supported by `ljf` function. From [TimeStored](http://www.timestored.com/b/kdb-lj-ij-uj-joins-and-upgrading-2-6-to-3-x/):

> The joins in 3.x for uj/ij and lj all changed how they treat nulls from the keyed table. In particular nulls now by default overwrite existing values. In the past nulls from the joining table did not overwrite and left the original value in the column

For more details and examples visit [TimeStored](http://www.timestored.com/b/kdb-lj-ij-uj-joins-and-upgrading-2-6-to-3-x/).

Comment: Thanks Anton. Any idea what `f` stands for in `ljf`?

Comment: Always welcome. And no idea why they used `f`, to be fair.

Comment: Had always thought it was 'f' for 'fill' - meaning that the nulls in the joining table were being 'filled' by values in the table being joined to

Comment: Thanks for tip @SeanHehir! `f` for filled sounds very reasonable.